# Determinant of the sum of matrices

Tags: determinant

Let *D* be a diagonal matrix and *A* a Hermitian one. Is there a nontrivial way to calculate the determinant of *A* from the determinant of *A+D* and the entries of *D*?

It can be assumed that the diagonal entries of *A* are all zeros.

Thankyou very much.

Comment: Well, if you assume that $A$ is a Hermitian matrix whose diagonal entries are all zeros, then $A$ has an eigenvalue of $0$, and consequently its determinant is $0$. So I've just ``recovered'' the determinant of $A$ for you and the determinants of $A+D$ and the entries of $D$ were not necessary.

Comment: @alex This is not always true, think for example of the matix formed by the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ in column form.

Comment: This has been crossposted to [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96691/determinant-of-the-sum-of-matrices). Perhaps someone with 50+ MO rep (I'm 1 point short!) could inform them?

Answer (score 2):

Take $A+D=\begin{pmatrix}
1& a& b\\
a& 1& c\\
b& c& 1
\end{pmatrix}$ with $a$, $b$, $c$ real.

Now, the entries of $D$ are 1 and the determinant of $A+D$ is $1+2abc-a^2-b^2-c^2$.

You want to recover $\det A=2abc$.

If you regard $a=b=1$ and $c=0$, then $\det A+D=-1$ and $\det A=0$.

But if you regard $a=b=1$ and $c=2$, then you also get $\det A+D=-1$, but $\det A=4$.

This example shows that your information is not sufficient to distinguish the two cases.
So, in general it is impossible to recover the determinant of the original matrix $A$.